# How to access base url value in java script function?

Tags: asp.net-2.0

i have to pass base url value from my "abc.master.cs" page to java script function which is on "abc.master" page.

I anyone know about this, then please help me!

Answer (score 0):

just create a protected string value on your cs as so:

```
protected string szBaseURL = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
```

and on your master page,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//this is the client side value    
var baseUrl = "<%= szBaseURL %>";
</script>
```